# (Edited + Example) Derive the formula for finding the center of the sphere and radius, if the coordinates of arbitrary the point are known

Tags: geometry, partial-derivative, matlab, spheres, newton-raphson

The general sphere formula is

R^2 = (x -a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2
[Above formula][1]

It can be transform into:

R = $ \sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2} $
[Formula 2][2]

Please, can you help me derive a general formula for finding coordinates of a, b, c and radius R of the sphere through the known coordinates x, y and z?

(P.s: Can you, please, show me how to derive this equation by using partial differential equation and how to derive this equation without partial differential equation?)

Comment: Please do not create new questions when editing the original question will be the appropriate thing to do. Just knowing a single point on a sphere will not determine the sphere. There are infinitely many spheres containing a single point.

Comment: Also in the main task it was said that we will find the estimated center of the sphere, and the point x is, as I think, the alleged real center of the sphere, and subtracting the values ​​from x, the values ​​of points a, b and c and using, for example, the Newton-Raphson method, we can find the minimum distance between the supposed center and the present, provided the iteration is stopped, the difference between the coordinates is 0. But this is only my assumption, as I said earlier I in a dead end and don't know hiw to solve this problem, to me its look almost impossible.

Comment: Try encasing your equations in dollar signs to make them more readable. For example, writing \$ \sqrt{x-c} \$ will display $\sqrt{x-a}$

Comment: What are the given sets of coordinates? Without multiple points, the problem is impossible

Comment: You are one condition too short for determining the position of the sphere.  Radius R can be treated variable to be determined by *method of least squares* used with data sets for surfaces here ( just like in two dimensions for curve fitting) described with detail in Claude Leibovici's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, according to the image, you have $n$ data points $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ supposed to be on a sphere and you look for the coordinates $(a,b,c)$ of its center as well as it radius $R$.

This is a typical problem which would require optimization and this implies that you need estimates for the unknown variables $(a,b,c,R)$. This can be done quite easily in a *preliminary* step considering $n$ equations
$$f_i=(x_i-a)^2+(y_i-b)^2+(z_i-c)^2 -R^2 =0$$
Build the $\frac {n(n-1)}2$ equations $f_j-f_i$ ($i$ varying from $1$ to $(n-1)$ and $j$ varying from $(i+1)$ to $n$) to get
$$2(x_i-x_j)a+2(y_i-y_j)b+2(z_i-z_j)c=(x_i^2+y_i^2+z_i^2)-(x_j^2+y_j^2+z_j^2)$$ So, a multilinear regression gives parameters $(a,b,c)$.

When this is done, you can estimates $R^2$ using
$$R^2=\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n \Big[(x_i-a)^2+(y_i-b)^2+(z_i-c)^2\Big]$$

Havig these estimates, you can polish the solution minimizing with respect to $(a,b,c,R)$ either
$$\Phi=\sum_{i=1}^n \Big[(x_i-a)^2+(y_i-b)^2+(z_i-c)^2-R^2\Big]^2$$ or
$$\Psi=\sum_{i=1}^n \Big[\sqrt{(x_i-a)^2+(y_i-b)^2+(z_i-c)^2}-R\Big]^2$$ and this can easily be done using Newton-Raphson method (if you are lazy, just use numerical derivatives after having written explicitely
$$\frac {\partial \Phi}{\partial a}=\frac {\partial \Phi}{\partial b}=\frac {\partial \Phi}{\partial c}=\frac {\partial \Phi}{\partial R}=0$$ which is simple.

I used this method with your data points : it works like a charm.

Comment: Thank You Very Much!!!